# Is there a non-romantic phrase for missing someone?

Tags: expressions, connotation, phrase-usage

The phrase "I miss you" can be equivocal: suggestive of (a) romantic longing and/or (b) regret of loss.

Certainly, context can shape its meaning, including geography, historical period, and the speakers and their relationships.

Given the circumstances in which it would be desirable to eliminate ambiguity, such as a platonic friendship, is there an alternative phrase for expressing (b) without (a)?

Comment: "I miss you" has too strong a connotation of romance? What region are you in?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have feelings for this girl?

Comment: Just say, “I miss you”. There's nothing wrong with that, and it's perfectly normal to say it to your friends (if you do in fact miss them), regardless of gender.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I agree, but there are people for whom a close but non-romantic relationship with a member of the opposite sex is unusual. Rye's question kind of hints in that direction, that if either of you doubts the nature of the feelings of the other then things can be awkward. Fortunately one the features of friendships is that innocent awkwardness can be overlooked.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd This comment is riddled with assumptions. Gender of the OP being the biggest one.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it belongs on the Dating.SE site instead.

Comment: @Cruncher Not to mention the sexual orientation or marital status of both parties, amongst other things.

Comment: @tchrist [Dating.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) got shut down, the format doesn't quite fit...

Comment: @pink-diamond-square I was jesting, and in fact, didn’t even know they had attempted this.

Comment: +1 for "Your absence has resulted in a sense of loss."  This should be on a Hallmark card.

Comment: Also, "I miss your friendship" comes across really strongly that you don't want the person to think you have romantic feelings for them, which might be awkward or even taken as an insult.  Just my take on it, of course, and it's all subjective.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Your absence has resulted in a sense of loss. (Pretty impersonal and somewhat morbid. I can picture this being said by some distant relative at a funeral.)
- It would be nice if you were here. (Flirtatious.)
- I miss your friendship. (Suggests that they *used* to be friends, but no longer are.)

How about:

- I miss hanging out together.
- It's boring here without you.
- Things aren't the same when you're not around.
- When are you coming to visit me?

The answer is highly subjective depending on how close the friendship is, the type of humor, how well 'they' know each other. What I mean by that is if they are very close and have a slightly naughty side they can get away with sexual connotations because they know their friendship will never go that way nor do they want it to (or at least one of them doesn't).

- I miss sleeping with you! (As in spending the night together for some reason, but not sex.)
- Did you replace me yet? (As in, did they find a new friend while you've been gone.)
- Remember the times when we'd... (Good for reminiscing.)
- I miss your ugly mug. (Old style for: I miss your face.)

Answer (score 7):

I miss you **chum**  or **pal** -both unromantic

Comment: And fairly anachronistic :p

Comment: +1 But reminds me of [this](http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20000928).

Answer (score 3):

- Stop being a stranger.
- Where've you been?!
- When you around again?
- Not seen you in ages.
- When you next free? We need a catchup.

Just be informal.

Comment: This is painful to read, typical of what a teenage girl would say to her crush.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very valid question, *and* it is hard to say you like someone without a hint of romance.

Maybe:  "It is good to see you again!" (with a smile) if they are around for a moment.

or: "I enjoy your company.  I wish you were around more often."

Answer (score -1):

"I'm feeling lonely without you", "Times are dull with you away" could express the sens of loss without being too emphatic.